# How to monitor API throttling in Django

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, throttling

I am building a solution where I have one core API on which I have implemented the throttling as per the official documentation `https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/throttling/`. But I wonder how will I be able to `monitor the requests so that no genuine user of the app gets blocked and if so should be able to unblock it.`

My settings.py file

```py
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_THROTTLE_CLASSES': (
        'rest_framework.throttling.ScopedRateThrottle',
    ),
    'DEFAULT_THROTTLE_RATES': {
        'students': '1/minute',
    }
}
```

And My views.py

```py
class StudentViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    throttle_scope = 'students'
```

Comment: What do you mean by a genuine user here? Is it an Open API?

Comment: By `genuine user` I mean a person who wants to consume the API only not like some bot/machine/person who is trying to break my system by brute force attack or some other ways.

Comment: Is it an Open API?

Comment: Yes, It's an open API.

Comment: So there is no way to know whether the request is genuine or not just by looking at it. What type of information will it serve? It is static information? How often will it change? In Which use case we need this information often? Can this be cached?

Comment: @luckyBarkane so, one of the ideas behind throttling is that a genuine user shouldn't perform actions that often anyway. So it should apply to everyone using the API. Of course, you have the increase the rates to something like 1/sec if it is an API that should receive requests often from the same user. Throttling isn't only for attackers but for official API clients as well, so they don't exceed their API limits and overload the server

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The throttle classes provided by Django REST framework do not allow you to do this. You would have to create a custom throttle class and overwrite `allow_request()` to log throttling events and provide some facility for whitelisting. E.g. something like this:

```
class WhitelistScopedRateThrottle(throttling.ScopedRateThrottle):

    def allow_request(self, request, view):
        allowed = super().allow_request(request, view)
        if not allowed:
            if self.is_whitelisted(request, view)
                return True
            else:
                self.log_throttling(request, view)
                return False
         else:
            return True

    def is_whitelisted(self, request, view):
        ...

    def log_throttling(self, request, view):
        ...
```

How to best implement the whitelisting and logging depends on your exact requirements.